# Можно ли в Google Play Console перезаписать опубликованное приложение другим APK-файлом?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Есть опубликованное приложение в Google Play Console. К примеру приложение `Example App` и идентификатором `com.example.app` Исходники приложения утеряны. Возможно ли перезаписать в качестве обновления новым приложением это старое опубликованное приложение? Например, если создать с нуля приложение с таким же идентификатором, а потом загрузить APK-файл в Google Play Console... Возможно ли такое провернуть?

Comment: Если подписать тем же ключом, то должно пропустить

Comment: Жаль... keystore-файл я благополучно потерял :(

Comment: Ааа, сам файл. Тогда выхода нет, только создавать новое приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для успешного обновления приложения должны быть выполнены три условия:

- совпадать `packageName`
- увеличен `versionCode`
- совпадать сертификат подписи

Если сертификат утерян, то только как новое приложение с новым `packageName`.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en